# Hide a div near the button when button gets clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ok, so I have this div with 100% height and 100% width and I have button centered into that div. Now when user clicks that button. I want the div to collapse near button and hide. Here is my code. and you can also see that on JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ZxB4Z/

```
$('button').click(function(){
$("div").animate({
  left:'24%',
  top:'48%',
  opacity:'0',
  height:'0px',
  width:'0px'
},'slow');});
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "I want the div to collapse near button and hide"?

Comment: Do you want it to collapse into where the button it. Like it's going into the button instead of the top left corner?

Comment: Yes @Leeish I want it to go to button like slowly reducing its height and width and opacity.

Comment: I think you will need to wrap the green div in another div. Set the green div to be centered with CSS. Then it will collapse into itself in the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use margin instead of position properties (top/left):

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $("div").animate({
        marginLeft:'24%',
        marginTop:'48%',
        opacity:'0',
        height:'0px',
        width:'0px'
    },'slow');
});
```

or apply position absolute on your div:

```
div { position: absolute }
```